# Sign or Initial or Signer Attachment Image not set for recipient

Tags: docusignapi

When making a request for a document through the Rest 2.0 API, I receive the error response:

```
{
  "errorCode": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",
  "message": "Sign or Initial or Signer Attachment Image not set for recipient {recipGUID}"
}
```

(actual GUID replaced)

The URL being accessed to get the document is

```
https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/5689423/envelopes/{guid}/documents/1?show_changes=true
```

The envelope in question contains one signer, with one signature and one signer attachment, both of which are filled out. The only recipient shows a correct signedDateTime value, indicating that it was signed and completed. When I view the document in docusign, I see both the signature image, as well as the attachment as the second page of the document.

This method has worked well for hundreds of other envelopes, but a small few seem to be giving me this message, even though it looks from my side like those documents are actually completed.

Comment: This appears to be a bug, I've sent you an email for follow up.

Answer (score 0):

This bug will be resolved on the next release to Production, I will update this post when that has been completed.

### Update:

This was fixed earlier this year and should no longer be an issue.